# Using map to change dates from string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have previously asked a question about converting string to dates - [Convert Date to String in nested array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786483/convert-date-to-string-in-nested-array-in-mongodb) - and got a great and working answer. The only issue is that when a date is a blank -> '' then I get the following error:

```
{
    "message" : "an incomplete date/time string has been found, with elements missing: ' '",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 241,
    "codeName" : "ConversionFailure",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

the formula Im using (taken from question) is:

```
db.cases.aggregate([
  { $match: { companyID: 218 }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "cases": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$cases",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$this",
            {
              "createddate": {
                "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$$this.createddate" }
              },
              "endDate": {
                "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$$this.endDate" }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

I have tried adding in

```
{ $unwind: "$cases" },
{ $match: { 'cases.endDate': {'$ne' : ''}}},
```

But that gave me an error saying:

```
{
    "message" : "input to $map must be an array not object",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 16883,
    "codeName" : "Location16883",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do `$group` after `$unwind` to get `$cases` back in array form

```
{ $unwind: "$cases" },
{ $match: { 'cases.endDate': {'$ne' : ''}}},
{ $group: {
  _id:$null,
  cases:{$push:'$cases'}
} },
```