# Store location data in Mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my current project , I am storing the location data in the following format in a Mongodb document

```
"location" : {
        "loc" : {
            "lng" : -118.15592692,
            "lat" : 34.03566804
        },
        "geocode" : {
            "city" : "East Los Angeles",
            "state" : "CA",
            "zipcode" : "90022",
            "countrycode" : "US",
            "country" : "United States"
        }
    }
```

There is a 2d index created on location.loc field:-

```
{
    "location.loc" : "2d"
}
```

But the geospatial queries are taking long time when the result set is large i.e more than 7000 records.
it seems to me that the index is not working . Is it because the data has not been stored in the format:-

```
loc: [-118.15592692, 34.03566804]
```

Please suggest what can be done to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your documents and create a new collection

```
db.location.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "location": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": ["$location.loc.lng", "$location.loc.lat"]
    },
    "geocode": "$location.geocode"
  }},
  { "$out": "location" }
])
```

Then create an index on `location` field

```
db.location.createIndex({ "location": "2d" })
```