# Overwriting a field with new data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

I am trying to overwrite the createddate and endDate from type string to a date type.

[image]

I have the code to change it from string to date ( Answered here [Convert Date to String in nested array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786483/convert-date-to-string-in-nested-array-in-mongodb) )

```
Cases.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "cases": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$cases",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$this",
            {
              "createddate": {
                "$cond": [
                  { "$eq": ["$$this.createddate", " "] },
                  null
                  { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$$this.createddate" } }
                ]
              },
              "endDate": {
                "$cond": [
                  { "$eq": ["$$this.endDate", " "] },
                  null
                  { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$$this.endDate" } }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Once this runs, it shows the dates as a date object, however once I refresh the document the date is back to a String again.

How can I save it so that it saves (overwrites) the value.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else wants to do this, I have found the answer.

```
db.cases.aggregate([
    { $match: { companyID: 218 }},
    { "$addFields": {
      "cases": { "$map": { "input": "$cases", "in": { "$mergeObjects": [ "$$this", {
        "createddate": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": ["$$this.createddate", " "] },
            null,
            { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$$this.createddate" } }
          ]
        },
        "endDate": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": ["$$this.endDate", " "] },
            null,
            { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$$this.endDate" } }
          ]
        }}]}}}
    }},
    { "$out": "cases" }
  ])
```

Thanks to @assh from question [Store location data in Mongodb document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895518/store-location-data-in-mongodb-document/59895711#59895711)